# Locking out certain user based on ip, but no the whole business network in PHP

Tags: php, security, authentication, ip

I have built a login system which locks out user after 4 failed attempts, logs the IP on the database and by a cookie (if cookie exists it does not re-validate on the database). The problem is if i lock out a user based on the IP, other computers won't have access with the same IP (same router). Is there a workaround on that? Could i generate or store something more specific about the user on the database?

Comment: This is not the only problem with identifying a user by IP.

Comment: Try setting a cookie, or fingerprinting the browser. In reality, not very possible.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, no. But you can make it safer with for example "evercookie", it's still removeable but 90% of users don't know how.
https://github.com/samyk/evercookie

Comment: One solution i came up with is setting a user token and IP relation in database so as to lock user on the same network but not other usernames..

Comment: But the client need to send username as well, so "bad user" can manipulate it - in my opinion no difference than sending simple cookie.

Comment: When you use pushpad(pushpad.xyz), a browser token is generated to send notifications. Do you know where this comes from or how can you get it by php?